# C# converting a long if statement to something more appropriate

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a `MDI form` where some of the children forms need a message box showing before being closed and others could be closed without asking. Because of a problem when calling `application.Exit()` from a `close event` of a child form I handle to `close event` of the parent and check where it was fired. If it was fired in a form that need a message box I call it otherwise just close the application. All this is implemented in this code:

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            SEdit se       = this.ActiveMdiChild as SEdit;
            SoEdit soleEdit = this.ActiveControl as SoEdit;
            UppEdit ue      = this.ActiveControl as UpEdit;
            MEdit mat  = this.ActiveControl as MEdit;
            LEdit lse      = this.ActiveControl as LEdit;
            CEdit cle    = this.ActiveControl as CEdit;

            if (se != null || soleEdit != null || ue != null || mat != null || lse != null || cle != null)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save before exit?", "Closing",
                      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                      MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("To Do saved.", "Status",
                              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
         }
```

I'm still learning but I know that such a long if-statement is a sign for bad code but i don't know how to improve it. What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: You use the cast only to check against null. Use the is operator instead - saves you six lines of code.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster I don't understand what you're saying.  How could you use the `is` operator here?

Comment: @JefferyKhan since Leron isn't actually doing anything with the casted result, by using `is` it just returns true/false, and IMO, far more readable: `if (ActiveMdiChild is SEdit || ActiveControl is SEdit || ActiveControl is SoEdit || ...)` (the check can/should still be moved to a local boolean or preferably a nicely named method as suggested below, but even in those I'd recommend using `is` still)

Comment: Ah, agreed!  I didn't quite realize he was casting the same control as different types to check against it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract condition to separate method:

```
private bool AnyChildAlive()
{
   return (this.ActiveMdiChild is SEdit) ||
          (this.ActiveControl is SoEdit) ||
          ...
          (this.ActiveControl is CEdit);
}
```

Then call this method (also use guard conditions to avoid nested if statements):

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{          
    if (!AnyChildAlive())
       return;

    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save before exit?", "Closing",
           MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
           MessageBoxIcon.Information) != DialogResult.Yes)
       return;

   MessageBox.Show("To Do saved.", "Status",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);     

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `is` be more appropriate here rather than using `as` + null check?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I thought about that, but result could be different is something equal to null, but have required type.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky `is` returns false if the object is `null`; I'm pretty sure it would produce the same result.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair my bad! Checked msdn, you were right. I updated answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way would be to create an Interface like:

```
public interface IFormActions {
  bool AskBeforeClosing();
  void SaveData();
}
```

Then, implement that interface for each of your forms and in the MainForm_FormClosing method do this:

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  IFormActions se = this.ActiveControl as IFormActions;
  if ((se != null) && se.AskBeforeClosing()) {
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save before exit?", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,  MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes) {
      se.SaveData();
      MessageBox.Show("Saved", "Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
  }
}
```

Because of how this is written, you wouldn't have to implement the interface for all of the forms, just the ones you actually want to ask the closing question for.

Comment: Agreed, very elegant solution indeed.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of making it more appealing on the eye or re-use, you may want to think about moving your validation to a different method.

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (FormIsValid())
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save before exit?", "Closing",
              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
              MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("To Do saved.", "Status",
                      MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                      MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}

private bool FormIsValid()
{
    return 
    (this.ActiveMdiChild as SEdit) != null ||
    (this.ActiveControl as SoEdit) != null ||
    (this.ActiveControl as UpEdit) != null ||
    (this.ActiveControl as MEdit)  != null ||
    (this.ActiveControl as LEdit)  != null ||
    (this.ActiveControl as CEdit)  != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  var objects = new List<object>
                {
                    this.ActiveMdiChild as SEdit,
                    this.ActiveControl as SoEdit,
                    this.ActiveControl as UpEdit,
                    this.ActiveControl as LEdit,
                    this.ActiveControl as CEdit
                };

        if (objects.Any(x => x != null))
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save before exit?", "Closing",
                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                  MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("To Do saved.", "Status",
                          MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                          MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but you could set the `Tag` property of the forms to 1 or 0 and check :

```
          if (this.ActiveControl.Tag == 1)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save before exit?", "Closing",
                      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                      MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("To Do saved.", "Status",
                              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
```